# Decimal number posted by view is natural number in controller

Tags: c#, view, controller, numbers, decimal

I have a form which has an input field of type number. The field contains decimal numbers which are passed correctly as far as I can see in my console:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryQKiycRaXM4F0HLVI
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ActivityMet"

19.6
```

Also, the Modelstate is valid in the controller. But when the value arrives, it is no longer a decimal number but an int. So, 19.6 would turn into 196. The very confusing part: I am using equivalent forms in 3 other places and it works in each and everyone of them.

My model looks like this:

```
public class UpdateActivityModels
    {
        [Required]
        public decimal ActivityMet { get; set; }
    }
```

So the form in my view looks like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/Administration/UpdateActivity" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<label class="control-label" for="ActivityMet">MET:</label>
<input name="ActivityMet" class="form-control text-right" id="ActivityMet" type="number" value="196" min="0" max="20" step="0.1">
<button id="saveEditActivityButton160" type="submit" data-loading-text="Save..." class="btn  btn-primary">Save</button></form>
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateActivity(UpdateActivityModels model){
            if (ModelState != null && ModelState.IsValid)
            {...}
}
```

Comment: Your input has a value="196" attribute.

Comment: This the preset value from the database. When I posted 19.6, it saved 196 to the database and when I clicked on the view again, 196 was the preset value..